# How can min-caml compiler got the type error?

Tags: ocaml, ml

I am learning https://github.com/esumii/min-caml

the example ack.ml under floder test:

```
let rec ack x y =
 if x <= 0 then y + 1 else
 if y <= 0 then ack (x - 1) 1 else
 ack (x - 1) (ack x (y - 1)) in
print_int (ack 3 10)
```

if I change the line

```
print_int (ack 3 10)
```

to this:

```
print_int (ack 3 1.23)
```

then make,got error:

```
Fatal error:exception Typing.Error(_,2,3)
```

I search the sorce,can't find info of Typing.Error,or Fatal.so how min-caml catch the type error?The ocaml compiler display in other way:

```
Error:this expression has type float but an expression was expected of type int
```

so where is the info

```
Fatal error:exception Typing.Error(_,2,3)
```

from?Thanks!

Comment: `ack 3 1.23`. You define `ack` to take two ints, but call it with the float value `1.23`. This creates a type error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Fatal error: exception ..." is the output you get for unhandled exceptions (in native executables at least, in the interpreter the message just says "Exception: ..."). So all that means is that a `Typing.Error` exception was raised and not handled.

`Typing.Error` refers to the exception `Error` defined in the `Typing` module. You'll find its definition in `typing.ml`:

```
exception Error of t * Type.t * Type.t
```

It's raised on [line 151 of typing.ml](https://github.com/esumii/min-caml/blob/8860b6fbc50786a27963aff1f7639b94c244618a/typing.ml#L151) by adding the syntax tree to a previously raised `Unify` exception.

`Unify` exceptions are raised at various points in the file when the type checker can't unify the actual and expected types.